# SQL - Shortening the query

Tags: sql-server

I have the below query.

```
with cte0 as (
    SELECT * FROM #Temp1 WHERE [Label] = 'B'
),
cte1 as (
    SELECT * FROM #Temp1 WHERE [Label] = 'A' AND [Value] > 20
)
SELECT * FROM cte0
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM cte1
```

The condition is very simple. I'm taking the all the records from a table which contains two columns namely - `[Label]` and `[Value]`, excluding the values < 20 only for column where `[Label]` = "A"

---

Data :

```
Label   Value
A   24
A   18
A   15
A   35
A   27
A   37
B   18
B   29
B   18
B   16
B   16
```

I'm using the query mentioned above to do that. But I wanted to do that in a single line without using any cte.

CONDITION: Need to select all the records excluding values less than 20 only for [Label] that has "A". 9 rows to be returned.

Help me out to overcome it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what's wrong with a CTE?

Comment: You **have** a single query.

Comment: Nothing's wrong. It's long :). I wanted to shorten it coz I have more 100 lines of sql query with more cte. That's why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `OR` and proper parenthesis:

```
SELECT * FROM #Temp1 
WHERE  [Label] = 'B'
OR    ([Label] = 'A' AND [Value] > 20)
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a9c90/3/0)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM #Temp1 WHERE ([Label] = 'A' AND [Value] > 20) OR (Label] = 'B')
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT * FROM #Temp1 WHERE [Label] = 'B'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM #Temp1 WHERE [Label] = 'A' AND [Value] > 20
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM #Temp1 WHERE ([Label] = 'B' ) OR ([Label] = 'A' AND [Value] > 20)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use OR here:

```
SELECT * FROM #Temp1 WHERE ( [Label] = 'B' ) OR ([Label] = 'A' AND [Value] > 20 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM #Temp1
WHERE Label = 'B'
OR    (Label = 'A' 
    AND value > 20)
```